# How to separate the full name that has comma in excel using php

Tags: php, sql, phpexcel

I have a project that gets the name from excel and stores the value in the first name and last name. The problem is that in the excel file the name is stored (for example John, Constantine) how do I get the John and Constantine and store it in two different variables?

```
if(isset($_POST['excel_btn']))
{
    require('import/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php');
    require('import/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

    $file=$_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
    

    $obj=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
    foreach($obj->getWorksheetIterator() as $sheet)
    {
        $getHighestRow=$sheet->getHighestRow();
        for($i=1; $i<=$getHighestRow; $i++){
            $name=$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();
           
             if($name !=''){
                 $query = "INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('$name')";
            
            $query_run=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            }
    }
}
```

this is what I wrote so far but with that, the full name is stored in the variable `$name`

Comment: `list($first, $last) = explode(', ', 'John, Constantine')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Updated)**

Use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) :

```
$pieces = explode(",", $name);
echo trim($pieces[0]); // John
echo trim($pieces[1]); // Constantine
```

Or, as @Markus Zeller:

```
list($first, $last) = explode(',', 'John, Constantine')
echo trim($first);
echo trim($last);
```

Comment: Don't *try* just use the `explode()` function. It will be also safer to split by comma without space like `','` and then echoing values using `trim()` - `echo trim($pieces[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regular expression which will split by comma or any space character. The optional flag PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY will make sure no empty matches will be returned. This trick also ensures trimming.

```
list($first, $last) = preg_split('/[,\s*]/', 'John, Doe', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

This will also work for strings like '   `John,    Doe`' and the results on both will be

```
$first = 'John';
$last  = 'Doe';
```